# Rename localhost folder. Gives empty screen

Tags: server, apache2, localhost, rename

I'm trying to rename my apache2 localhost folder.

I have already gone to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site-name`
and changed the following lines in the  Document:

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html
Directory /home/user/public_html
```

'public_html' is then the new name of my localhost.

Then i restarted the apache2 server, but this does not work as when i type 'localhost' in my browser i just get an empty screen.

What else must I do to change the folder name of my localhost?

My system is an L-Ubuntu 11.04, by the way.

Comment: Do you have the right settings related to mod_rewrite (only if you have the module enabled of coures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loaded configuration file is at:
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

There the 'auto_prepend' file needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add correct port in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`